# How to add a custom domain to IBM cloud engine

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudflare, ibm-cloud-code-engine

we are migrating from IBM Cloud Foundry Orgs (as they are [depreciated](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry-public?topic=cloud-foundry-public-deprecation))  to ibm cloud engine.

but what seems impossible is the "routes" option that was available in CF (cloud foundry). With CF we could just CNAME the custom domain to *eu-de.cf.appdomain.cloud* and add it to the routes of the application.

With cloud engine, the only way we can setup a custom domain is explained [here](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-ibm-cloud-code-engine-application), but this requires an extra service from cloudflare.

Is there a way to migrate the CF setup to IBM cloud engine without the Cloudflare worker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment that is not possible. That being said the Code Engine team is working on a solution to enable this without requiring requiring an extra service (although the proposed cloudflare service in the blog is free AFAIK)

Comment: Strange of IBM, that this is not yet available. In less than 6 months we need another solution and this seems like a basic functionality. Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to [deploy a proxy on your own and use it to handle the domains](https://blog.4loeser.net/2022/05/custom-domain-ibmcloud-code-engine.html). I have used Traefik for it, but nginx and others should work, too. I deployed the proxy to a Kubernetes cluster which worked well.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into Kubernetes cluster. But of course this is a bit more complex than just putting a route in a web interface as it was with CF.

Comment: I agree on complexity and wait for the custom domain integration into Code Engine